# C++ - Get typename of a template where that class is used as another template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, typename

I would like to get the typename of a class template from another class that use a tamplate based on the first class.

I have wrote a class like so:

```
template<typename T>
class class_a {
  ...
}
```

I would like to do something that:

```
template<class class_a>
class class_b {
  std::vector<class_a.T> arr;
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can't do that directly. That's why standard containers have member types such as (for example) `std::vector::value_type`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have your templates "cooperate" with each other, and for `class_a` to "help" the other template:

```
template<typename T>
class class_a {

public:
   typename T type_t;
};
```

And then:

```
template<class class_a>
class class_b {
  std::vector<typename class_a::type_t> arr;
  ...
};
```

You will find this to be a pretty much standard design pattern in the C++ library itself. Most C++ containers, for example, define `value_type`, so if we changed the `typedef` to `value_type`:

```
template<typename T>
class class_a {

public:
   typename T value_type;
};
```

And then:

```
template<class class_a>
class class_b {
  std::vector<typename class_a::value_type> arr;
  ...
};
```

Then if your `class_b` were to be instantiated using a `std::list`, for example:

```
class_b<std::list<char>> b;
```

Then your `arr` will end up being `std::vector<char>`.

An alternative that does not require this "cooperation" would be to use a helper template with specialization, in order to avoid having to explicitly declare a `typedef` alias. However this is the simplest solution unless you have some specific reason not to do things this way.

Comment: Yes. But rather than using the old style `typename T type_t;` prefer the modern form of type aliasing `using type_t = T;`.

Comment: Whether I use `type_t` or `value_type` I get this error: `error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘T’`

Comment: I, of course, have no knowledge of exactly how and in which way you "use `type_t` or `value_type`", and which specific line results in an error. This is fairly fundamental stuff, and in your C++ textbook there should be many examples like this that you can imitate.